# How to disable translations using angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, translation, angular-translate

I am using angular-translate in my application. I want to give my user possibility to temporarily disable all translations in my application without refreshing the whole page.

How can do that? I tried setting language / refreshing language which does not exists, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> setting <...> language which does not exists

I don't known why, but it working only after second `use()` function call;
This function disable all translates:

```
$scope.test = function(){
    $translate.use('xx');
    $translate.use('xx');
};
```

*I would be thankful, if someone explained, how it works;*